# jQuery + CSS element change

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following code to set all classes of the element to `display:none` with the exception of the first instance.

How would I modify the code to set the classes all the elements to`display:none` with the exception of the SECOND instance only.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('selectorForElement').slice(1).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A conjunction of [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selectors should do it:

```
$('.selectorForElement:not(:eq(1))').hide();
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epJZZ/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('selectorForElement:eq(0), selectorForElement:gt(1)').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('selectorForElement:eq(0)').css('display', 'none'); 
    $('selectorForElement:gt(1)').css('display', 'none'); 
});
```

The `:eq(0)` selector will select the first element in the selector (index equals 0).  The `:gt(1)` selector will select all items with an index greater than 1 which skips the first and second elements.  The result is everything but the second element.

Comment: What would I do to implement this then for the 3rd instance and so on?

Comment: @VincePettit I think Darin has the best answer here.  His use of `:not(eq(1))` allows you to filter out a specific element.  Indexes are 0 based so you'd need `:not(eq(2))` to filter out the 3rd.